# Need power supply suggestion(s)

Tags: power-supply, power

I need a + and - 200vdc (common ground) at 100ma max power supply. Regulation of 2% is fine. Input is 120vac. I know how to build a bridge supply but I haven't found a transformer cheap enough. They are all > $50. I'm not asking anyone to do my work. Just wondering if anyone here has already done this. It will be used to power a 24vdc supply used in a UPS system for testing. Won't be on for much longer than 30 seconds. Cost of $20-$30 for parts would be cool.

Comment: I agree. Cost of $20-$30 would be good. I've no idea how you'll achieve a dual rail power supply able to deliver 40 watts total with new stuff. I think you'll need to find something discarded and free, to start off. If you figure this out, let me know. But here's a [10 mA example](https://www.ti.com/tool/PMP20183) to give an idea.

Comment: What is the cheapest 24 volt output SMPS you can find? If it’s $15 then adding a flyback circuit to produce what you want is within catching distance.